# How to remove "debugger eval code" at the end of the output in console

Tags: javascript, firefox, console.log

I'm using Firefox 66.0.3.

When I execute the following snippet

```
[1,1,5,76,7,8,8,85,8,5,85,5,5,55].forEach(x => console.log(x))
```

or whatever code that has `console.log()` the browser shows `debugger eval code` at the end of the line in the output.

[image: example image]

How to remove "debugger eval code" from output?

Comment: I have to ask... why does it matter?

Comment: I want to copy the whole output, without this `debugger eval code`

Comment: That's just the way the console works, the right side shows where every log message comes from.

Comment: Is there a setting to remove that ?

Answer (score 3):

> Unfortunately there is no way (at this date) to disable that but there
>   is a way for solving your problem

Define an array with one "\n" element:

```
temp = ["\n"]
```

Add each of your message with "\n" at end to array

```
temp.push(message+"\n")
```

Then log the array with spread operator

```
console.log(...temp)
```

---

now you log your whole messages with just **ONE eval code**

you can now easily select all the log without eval code because of first "\n" element

Answer (score 1):

Join your list with line breaks:

```js
console.log([1,1,5,76,7,8,8,85,8,5,85,5,5,55].join('\n'))
```

You can then safely copy the result without the `debugger eval code` strings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's similar to the other answers. I thought there is a option in Firefox to enable/disable this. In more complex situations it's not that easy to use `.join('\n')`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this when trying to scrape some data I didn't want to try to copy and paste due to the other garbage that would have come with the data I wanted, so I will presume your case is similar.

If so, just use window.alert() instead of console.log() to prevent the extra characters.

The new code would become:

```
 window.alert([1,1,5,76,7,8,8,85,8,5,85,5,5,55])
```

or

```
collection = [1,1,5,76,7,8,8,85,8,5,85,5,5,55]; window.alert(collection);
```

Comment: is some cases, like the example in the descriptions, I just want to log the current result. If I need to use alert: `.forEach(x => alert(x))`, it will be annoying, the other way is to concatenate with new line characters. But still it became complex